# How to resolve this selection sort in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, selection-sort

I am implementing Selection Sort Algorithm in java using ArrayList.
Algorithm I implemented is correct but I am not getting valid output.
can anyone help me please if I am going wrong with this Arraylist.
code :

```
import java.util.*;
public class SelectionSort {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    array.add(50);
    array.add(30);
    array.add(10);
    array.add(60);
    array.add(40);
    System.out.println(array);
    selsort(array);

}
private static ArrayList<Integer> selsort(ArrayList<Integer> array){
    int i = 0;
    int imin = 0;
    int len = array.size();
    for (i = 0;i <len-1; i++){
        imin = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j<len; j++) {
            if ((Integer) (array.get(j)) < (Integer) (array.get(imin))){
                    imin = j;
            }
            Collections.swap(array,i,j);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(array);
    return array;

}
}
```

output :

> [50, 30, 10, 60, 40]  //before
>   [40, 60, 10, 30, 50] //after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are swapping the elements with the wrong indices in the wrong place.
The correct swap is `i` with `imin`.
The correct place is outside the inner loop:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> selsort(ArrayList<Integer> array){
    int i = 0;
    int len = array.size();
    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        int imin = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (array.get(j) < array.get(imin)) {
                imin = j;
            }
        }
        Collections.swap(array,i,imin);      
    }
    System.out.println(array);
    return array;
}
```

> [50, 30, 10, 60, 40]
>   [10, 30, 40, 50, 60]

Comment: @minigeek you are welcome. Yes I did remove the casting since it is not needed because you have a generic ArrayList which ensures that whatever you take out is an `Integer` anyway.

Comment: it was showing me error before..donno why..now it isn't